# Whats wrong with this simple python code?

Tags: python

```
x = 5
if x < 2:
  print ('Below 2')
  elif > 2
    print ('Two or more')
    else:
      print ('Something Else')
```

Comment: The indentation and the colon after the elif statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong, you never referenced your variable `x` in the `elif` statement and you are missing a colon on line 4:

```
x = 5
if x < 2:
    print ('Below 2')
elif x > 2:
    print ('Two or more')
else:
    print ('Something Else')
```

Comment: geezzzz....
i actually didnt type it the way i ran it, there was a reference to x and a colon in my initial code.... but my indentation was off course ;(.
Im so happy you helped me resolved this. didnt know indentation could cause that. thanks